Implementing BLE OTA Encrypted Updates with Swift and ESP-IDF
I've been working on this issue for a few days now but haven't found a solution. The ESP32 forum isn't very active, so I haven't received much help there.
I'm trying to encrypt an ESP .bin file (on my Mac) and update the firmware on my ESP32 by uploading it through my iOS Swift app (BLE).
When uploading I get the following ESP32 serial information (already after receiving one package):
E (34658) esp_encrypted_img: Magic Verification failed E (34658) NimBLE_BLE_OTA: Error in decryption: -1
I followed the documentation available here to generate this Swift code for sending the data in packages:
    func calculateCRC16(_ data: Data) -> UInt16 {
        var crc16: UInt16 = 0
        for byte in data {
            crc16 = crc16 ^ UInt16(byte) << 8
            for _ in 0..<8 {
                crc16 = (crc16 & 0x8000) != 0 ? (crc16 << 1) ^ 0x1021 : crc16 << 1
            }
        }
        return crc16
    }

func initPackets() {
        let totalSectors = (firmwareData!.count + 4095) / 4096
        var packets = [Data]()

        for sectorIndex in 0..<totalSectors {
            let sectorStart = sectorIndex * 4096
            let sectorEnd = min((sectorIndex + 1) * 4096, firmwareData!.count)
            let sectorData = firmwareData!.subdata(in: sectorStart..<sectorEnd)
            
            var packetSeq: UInt16 = 0
            var start = 0
            while start < sectorData.count {
                let end = min(start + EXPECTED_PACKET_SIZE, sectorData.count)
                var packet = Data()
                packet.append(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: UInt16(sectorIndex).bigEndian) { Data($0) })
                packet.append(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: packetSeq.bigEndian) { Data($0) })
                packet.append(sectorData[start..<end])

                if start + EXPECTED_PACKET_SIZE >= sectorData.count {
                    packetSeq = 0xFF // Last packet of the sector
                    let crc16 = calculateCRC16(sectorData)
                    packet.append(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: crc16) { Data($0) })
                    packet.append(contentsOf: [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: EXPECTED_PACKET_SIZE - packet.count))
                }
                
                start = end
                packetSeq += 1
                packets.append(packet)
            }
        }
        self.packets = packets // Store prepared packets
    }
    
    func sendNextPacket(for peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        guard !packets.isEmpty else {
            sendEndCommand(for: peripheral)
            return
        }
        
        let packet = packets.removeFirst()
        writePacketToOTACharacteristic(packet, for: peripheral)
    }

    func sendStartCommand(for peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        var packet = Data()
        packet.append(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: UInt16(OTACommandID.start).bigEndian) { Data($0) })
        packet.append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: UInt8(0), count: 18 - packet.count)) // Fill the rest)
        writePacketToOTACharacteristic(packet, for: peripheral)
    }

    func sendEndCommand(for peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        var packet = Data()
        packet.append(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: UInt16(OTACommandID.end).bigEndian) { Data($0) })
        packet.append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: UInt8(0), count: 18 - packet.count)) // Fill the rest
        writePacketToOTACharacteristic(packet, for: peripheral)
    }


    func writePacketToOTACharacteristic(_ packet: Data, for peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if let characteristic = characteristicsDictionary[peripheral.identifier]?[otaDataCharacteristicUUID] {
            peripheral.writeValue(packet, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
        }
    }

This code is also modeled after the Android example code.
For receiving the data, I primarily use the "nimble_ota.c" example included in the Espressif BLE OTA component.
The relevant code for decrypting is:
static void
esp_ble_ota_write_chr(struct os_mbuf *om)
{
  
#ifndef CONFIG_OTA_WITH_PROTOCOMM
  esp_ble_ota_char_t ota_char = find_ota_char_and_desr_by_handle(attribute_handle);
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_PRE_ENC_OTA
  esp_err_t err;
  pre_enc_decrypt_arg_t pargs = {};

  pargs.data_in_len = om->om_len - 3;

  if (SLIST_NEXT(om, om_next) != NULL)
  {
    struct os_mbuf *temp2 = SLIST_NEXT(om, om_next);
    pargs.data_in_len += temp2->om_len;
  }

  pargs.data_in = (const char *)malloc(pargs.data_in_len * sizeof(char *));
  err = os_mbuf_copydata(om, 3, pargs.data_in_len, pargs.data_in);

  if (om->om_data[2] == 0xff)
  {
    pargs.data_in_len -= SECTOR_END_ID;
  }

  err = esp_encrypted_img_decrypt_data(decrypt_handle_cmp, &pargs);
  if (err != ESP_OK && err != ESP_ERR_NOT_FINISHED)
  {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error in decryption: %d", err);
    return;
  } else {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Decryption successful");
  }
#endif

Why does this happen? How can I resolve it? I have completely reworked my code because I couldn't fix the issue initially, but I still receive the magic verification error.
The file is encrypted. Also the example .bin file produced the same result.

You're trying to take two big steps simultaneously, sending a firmware image over BLE and doing encrypted updates. I suggest you tackle them separately, first do send an unencrypted image, after this works then try encryption. Anyway, seems like decryption fails after receiving the first 4 bytes which are supposed to contain the magic bytes 0x0788b6cf. Whatever you're sending is in wrong format.

Thank you very much for your response. I reviewed the details using a hex editor and by examining the serial prints, and I realized that I had mistakenly used two bytes for the sequence number in my Swift code instead of one. Consequently, I've modified my Swift code:
var packet = Data()
packet.append(contentsOf: withUnsafeBytes(of: UInt16(sectorIndex).bigEndian) { Data($0) })
packet.append(UInt8(packetSeq))
It's still not working (I have to look into this), but I got a lot further now.
